# Sliding inner product using Tensorflow convolution

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors of shape N x D1 and M x D2 where D1 > D2, called X and Y respectively. For my task, X acts as the input and Y acts as the filter.

I want to calculate a matrix P of shape N x M x (D1-D2+1) such that:

```
P[0,0,0] = dot(X[0,0:D2], Y[0,:]) 
P[0,0,1] = dot(X[0,1:D2+1], Y[0,:]) 
... 
P[N-1,M-1,D1-D2] = dot(X[N-1,D1-D2:D1], Y[M-1,:])
```

I can create a for loop and manually slide Y and calculate the dot products. 
However I prefer using the correlation operator. 
As I know, tensorflow has correlation operator implemented (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn/convolution) but I don't know how can I use my tensors as inputs and filters.

Answer (score 0):

tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu=None, data_format=None, name=None)

In your case, I'd set strides to 1, and padding to SAME.

tf.nn.conv2d(X, Y, strides=1, padding=SAME)

Comment: I don't think the conv2d gives what I want. 
Intuitively, what I want is to have every row of Y convolve with every row of X. I can do it by looping over all the rows of X and Y and do convolution. I can also do the trick with for loop, slicing and pair-wise multiplication (which is working fine). Nevertheless I don't know is there any better way to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use indeed tf.nn.conv2d(), but you should add both batch and channel dimensions:

```
X = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(X,0),-1) 
# X.shape [batch=1, in_height, in_width, in_channels=1] 
Y = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(Y,-1),-1)
# Y.shape = [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels=1, out_channels=1]

# Convolution (actually correlation, see doc of conv2d) 
xcorr = tf.nn.conv2d(X, Y, padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1])
# Padding should be VALID, since you've already padded your input
```

CAVEAT: However, you cannot extrapolate this approach for batches of signals, since  tf.nn.conv2d uses always the same filter over the batch dimension, and from my understanding you do want to change it.